# facebook doesn't see image when sharing

Tags: facebook, tags, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to share [this page](http://www.watchfit.com/article/The-health-benefits-of-honey/124) but the Facebook tags are not seen. If I use facebook test tool: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.watchfit.com%2Farticle%2FThe-health-benefits-of-honey%2F124

It shows `302 error` for the page, though I don't see why. These are the facebook tags:

```
<\meta property="og:title" content="The health benefits of honey" /\>
<\meta property="og:url" content="http://www.watchfit.com/article/The-health-benefits-of-honey/124" /\>
<\meta property="og:description" content="Health benefits of Honey. The medical benefits of Honey, especially Manuka Honey. Two recipes from the Leon cookbook" /\>
<\meta property="og:site_name" content="watchfit.com" /\>
<\meta property="og:image" content="http://www.watchfit.com/uploads/articles/224X224/1363093263.jpg" /\>
```

Anyone knows what could be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Look carefully at the debugger response and you'll see it tell you your image is too small, despite being in a 224X224 folder its only 152 pixels high.